# Is using google search programmatically allowed by Google?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, google-search

I need to implement UISearchBar which does google search on iPhone app.
(Like any browser as Safari, Chrome for iPhone and etc.)

I plan to implement this by following way according to this answer. 
[How do I Setup my UISearchBar connected to my UIWebView to be able to search on google with a word instead of a url using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447880/how-do-i-setup-my-uisearchbar-connected-to-my-uiwebview-to-be-able-to-search-on)

```
text = text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+");
var url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com/search?q=".stringByAppendingString(text));
```

The problem is Google says if you sent heavy search query to google search programmatically, Google may ban the access.

A google search bar on iPhone app will certainly not send heavy search query within a short time so I assume this won't be a problem.

Anyone knows the answer with reasonable information source?

Comment: A search bar on a single iPhone will probably not be a problem. A search bar on 100,000 iPhones would be. Your best bet is to use the GoogleSDK search bar. You can use that for free. I am using the location search bar at the moment and it has no limits as log as you use the one made by google.

Comment: Does the Google SDK support simple google search? It seems only supports Map Search.